# Spree Commerce installation error, Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, spree

At the time I install the Spree site (in according with this guide: http://guides.spreecommerce.com/getting_started.html) , I get this problem:

> deploy@bothunter:~/rails$ sudo -i gem install rails
>   Successfully installed rails-3.2.1
>   1 gem installed
>   deploy@bothunter:~/rails$ sudo -i gem install bundler
>
> Successfully installed bundler-1.0.22      1 gem installed
>   deploy@bothunter:~/rails$ sudo -i gem install spree
>   Successfully installed spree-1.0.0 1 gem installed
>   deploy@bothunter:~/rails$ rails new mystore -d mysql create
>         create  README.rdoc
>         create  Rakefile
>         create  config.ru
>         .....
>
> run  bundle install
>   Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org/
>   Using rake (0.9.2.2)
>   Using activemodel (3.2.1)
>    ..... 
>   Using rack-test (0.6.1)
>   Using hike (1.2.1)
>   Using actionpack (3.2.1)
>    ..... 
>   Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
>   Using jquery-rails (2.0.0)
>   Using mysql2 (0.3.11)
>   Using rails (3.2.1)
>   Using uglifier (1.2.3)
>   Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
>
> deploy@bothunter:~/rails$ cd mystore
>   deploy@bothunter:~/rails/mystore$ spree install
>   Would you like to install the default gateways? (yes/no) [yes]
>       ... 
>   gemfile  spree
>   gemfile  spree_usa_epay
>   gemfile  spree_skrill     run
>   bundle install from "."
>   **git://github.com/spree/spree_usa_epay.git (at 0cb57b4) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` precompiling  assets**
>
> **git://github.com/spree/spree_usa_epay.git (at 0cb57b4) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`**
>
> deploy@bothunter:~/rails/mystore$ bundle install
>      **Updating git://github.com/spree/spree_usa_epay.git**
>
> **Updating git://github.com/spree/spree_skrill.git**
>   Fetching source index for sitename.com
>   **Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
>
>   **In Gemfile:**
>           **spree_usa_epay (>= 0) ruby depends on**
>             **rails (<= 3.1.3, >= 3.1.1) ruby**
>
> ```
>     **rails (3.2.1)**
> ```
>
> deploy@bothunter:~/rails/mystore$

But...

> ```
> deploy@bothunter:~/rails/mystore$ gem --list
>
> rails (3.2.1, **3.1.3**)
> railties (3.2.1, **3.1.3**)
> rake (0.9.2.2, 0.9.2)
> ```

How to solve it?

Comment: you should not install gems with `sudo -i`

Comment: having the same problem also.  Right now I'm using rbenv to manage my ruby versions, but thinking of switching back to RVM so that I have control over my gemsets, that way I can manage which rails gem to use per project or whatever.

Comment: 'you should not install gems with sudo -i'
   

@mpapis, it doesn't matter, because with "sudo gem" the same situation...
i think, that:

# gem 'spree_usa_epay', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_usa_epay.git', :ref => '0cb57b4afbf1eef6a0ad67a4a1ea506c6418fde1'
# gem 'spree_skrill', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_skrill.git', :ref => '37e6159aa71ec053499e2c7aa9cf799a3b3bdb39'
has old dependencies... no?

Comment: sudo -i is bad idea it might change the environment and the place where gems are installed, as for the error, have you tried running `bundle install` as advertised ?

Comment: @mpapis, I did it (exit, su deploy...), but:
  In Gemfile:
spree_skrill (>= 0) ruby depends on  
spree_core (>= 0.70.1) ruby  

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resol.

deploy@bothunter:~/rails/mystore$ bundle update
Updating git://github.com/spree/spree_usa_epay.git
Updating git://github.com/spree/spree_skrill.git
Fetching source index for site
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    spree_usa_epay (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rails (<= 3.1.3, >= 3.1.1) ruby

    rails (3.2.1)

Comment: after rereading question I found that it asks for `bundle install precompiling assets` and then `bundle install`

Answer (score 5):

Spree 1.0 only works with Rails 3.1.3. We'll be looking at supporting Rails 3.2 in the next minor release of Spree. Until that comes out, use 3.1.3, like this:

```
gem install rails -v 3.1.3
```

Comment: Just want to add that you also change the version to 3.1.3 in Gemfile

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure the problem here is that the rails version has progressed ahead of what spree is expecting. So if you create the new rails app with the 3.1.3 version by typing in:

```
rails _3.1.3_ new my_app_name
```

then you will get past this error. However, after that, I got another error during bundle install that I have not yet solved.